# PHP: Switch check same value from multiple variables

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am setting Switch to select font family for multiple places. For instance for `body` and for `paragraph`. Both has own selection dropdown but same font family. Means body as arial, tahoma, verdana than paragraph also has the same families.

So for body I have set switch-case and works fine but than now I want to use same font family for paragraph. So how can I use same switch case for two different variables?

```
$body = get_opt('body_fonts');
$para = get_opt('para_fonts');

switch ($body) {
    case 'Arial':
        $body_fonts = 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
        break;

    case 'Lucida':
        $body_fonts = '"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif';
        break;

    case 'Roboto':
        $body_fonts = '"Roboto", sans-serif;';
        break;

    case 'Tahoma':
        $body_fonts = 'Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif';
        break;

    case 'Verdana':
        $body_fonts = 'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif';
        break;

    default:
        $body_fonts = 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
        break;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry! I did some undo and by mistake removed some text.. added line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to enclose your code in a function:

```
function getfont($what) {
    switch ($what) {
        case 'Arial':
            $fonts = 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
            break;

        case 'Lucida':
            $fonts = '"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif';
            break;

        case 'Roboto':
            $fonts = '"Roboto", sans-serif;';
            break;

        case 'Tahoma':
            $fonts = 'Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif';
            break;

        case 'Verdana':
            $fonts = 'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif';
            break;

        default:
            $fonts = 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
            break;
    }
    return $fonts;
}

$body_fonts = getfont($body);
$para_fonts = getfont($para);
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach may be to make a map.

```
$fontMap = array(
    'Arial'=>'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
    'Lucida'=>'"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif',
    'Roboto'=> '"Roboto", sans-serif',
    'Tahoma'=>'Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif',
    'Verdana'=>'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif',
    'default'=>'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'
);
```

Then you can do something like this

```
$bodyFonts = array_key_exists($body, $fontMap)?$fontMap[$body]:$fontMap["default"];
$paraFonts = array_key_exists($para, $fontMap)?$fontMap[$para]:$fontMap["default"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a loop with variable variables:

```
$elements = array($body, $para);

foreach($elements as $element) {
    switch ($element) {
        case 'Arial':
            ${$element .'_fonts'} = 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif';
            break;

        #other case statements here
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is a very good approach, though. You might want to refactor your code into more functions.